# logstash convert to date and use only the date part in kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

Really am a beginner in Elasticsearch..
I have field in my csv is the following formt: "2020-01-31T07:01:56+00:00"
I want this field to be a date field so I can later use kibana to aggregate and filter it by date only e.g. 2020-01-31

Is this the way to do it or do I need to mutate it in other way?

```
mutate {
    convert => ["purchase-date", "date"]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Found how to do it:

```
date {
    match => ["purchase-date",  "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ" ]
    timezone => "UCT"
    target => "@timestamp"
}
```

and then in Kibana to use the Date Histogram